# Changing duplicate values in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of lists of numbers, e.g.:

```
tDict = {1:[400,200,400,100,0],2:[100,200,300,400,400],3:[200,200,200,100,100]}
```

I am not allowed to have duplicate values in the lists so my strategy is to iterate through and replace duplicate values with incremented values. This would produce:

```
{1:[400,200,401,100,0],2:[100,200,300,400,401],3:[200,201,202,100,101]
```

I have tried multiple combinations of counters etc to achieve this:

```
for k,v in tdict.items():
    for x in range(len(v)):
        for y in range(len(v):
            if v[x]==v[y] and y!0
                v[y]+=1
```

etc. (Im pretty new to python as you can probably guess). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there are point of incrementing the duplicate values or why not just remove them? Just trying to understand the logic.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I wonder, if is is even possible to add multiple equal `values` to one `key` of a `dict`. How is that `dict` created? Are those `values` assigned one by one or is a `list` created and that list is assigned to a `key`?

Comment: @MaxM it seems the dictionary has unique keys (obviously), but the values are just lists

Comment: The question is, how those `lists` be assigned to a `key`? Assigning the values only would be a more proper way to go, if not multiple `lists` are possibly added to one `key`

Comment: @xander : im making a transaction database for sequential analysis. so duplicate values are not allowed so you have to rethink them.

Comment: @ haccks :a solution to the programming problem described is required. I supposes the question is " how is this done pythonesquely?"

Comment: @Max M it is a dictionary of lists assigned to keys. only single lists are added . I parsed them in from json myself. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) building a new dict from each of the lists and then incrementing the count object when a new instance of an integer is found. The current count is then added to the number:

```
from itertools import count

for k, v in tDict.items():
   d = {k: count() for k in v}
   tDict[k] = [x+next(d[x]) for x in v]

print tDict
# {1: [400, 200, 401, 100, 0], 
#  2: [100, 200, 300, 400, 401], 
#  3: [200, 201, 202, 100, 101]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
for k, v in tDict.iteritems():
   new_list = []
   for item in v:
       while item in new_list:
           item += 1
       new_list.append(item)
   tDict[k] = new_list
```

Comment: is this missing an import for iteritems or something? Im a newb and i like how clear the code is here as things like nested list comps are less intuitive. thanks for this anyway.

Comment: @steveeweeveewoo no import is required. Should work as is.

Comment: iteritems does not work in Python3: I should have specified . my bad.